# cannot use #include "FS.h" #include "SD_MMC.h" in my local project of arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino, esp32

I was trying to used `#include "SD_MMC.h"` in my code with esp32 dev board, but when try on in include this file in my library .h file which i tend to have my own routines to handle the SD card.

when i include  `#include "SD_MMC.h"` this file in my `test.c` which have some function relating to sd card read/write, i get this error

```
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.3\libraries\FS\src/FS.h:24:10: fatal error: memory: No such file or directory
 #include <memory>
          ^~~~~~~~
```

this my setup.

```
#include"test.h"

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

test.c file

```
#include"test.h"
#include "SD_MMC.h"
```

test.h this file is empty at the moment.

But, if i include this file in the main file it works without any issue.

```
#include"test.h"
#include "SD_MMC.h"

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: `#include <memory>` looks like a C++ library, so it sounds like you should use C++ instead of C.

Comment: @MikeCAT  They’re using Arduino, which is C++, though they probably don’t know it.

Comment: Renaning files to test.hpp and test.cpp, worked !

Comment: add `#include <Arduino.h>`